# Existing Raspbian Installation in Qemu on Windows

Tags: raspbian, image, emulation, qemu

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B running Raspbian NOOBS, which I'm preparing to use as a media centre / Node.JS server.

I have followed various tutorials and managed to get a premade Raspbian image up and running with Qemu on my Windows 8 laptop. I am, however, unable to get a .img file which I made using Win32DiskImager (a clone of the SD card which contains my functioning Raspbian install) to boot in Qemu.

The image and Qemu installation provided at http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/ is nice and clean and quick and it functions, but swapping the .img for my own, I receive the following messages in the Qemu window:

> No filesystem could mount root, tried: reiserfs ext3 ext2 ext4 cramfs minix vfat ntfs romfs fuseblock
>       Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,2)

I'm using the following command sequence to run Qemu:

> $ qemu-system-arm.exe -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -hda raspbian.img -kernel kernel-qemu -m 192 -append "root=/dev/sda2"

I tried different `sda` values, and I tried using `rootfstype=msdos` and `rootfstype=fat32` since the SD is FAT32 formatted. I've tried using `qemu-system-armw.exe` instead of `qemu-system-arm.exe`. I've tried different versions of Qemu while following different tutorials, all with similar results -- an unmountable filesystem. Yet Qemu shows 5 partitions before it errors out. I tried reimaging the SD card -- and ended up with an identical image (same MD5, same total filesize).

So far every tutorial or forum thread I've found discusses creating a new installation for emulation, whereas what I need is to have a clone of my existing, configured system available to me while I'm away from home. Is there a method to achieve this using tools available for Windows 8?

I have read through the following tutorials:

- http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/
- http://techny.tumblr.com/post/36589722093/quick-guide-on-emulating-a-raspberry-pi-in-windows
- http://raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=37386&start=25 (the post by d4n13 on Mon 20 May 2013 at 8:14 pm)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but since it comes up in Google searches and I was looking for the same information, I'll post what I've found.

There's a solution for Linux based qemu [here](https://www.bentasker.co.uk/documentation/linux/267-testing-raspberry-pi-images-with-qemu) and there's Windows based information [here](https://gitlab.maikel.pro/maikeldus/WhatsSpy-Public/issues/200).

Comment: This looks promising. I will give it a try this week. If it works, you've got yourself a green checkmark. If it doesn't, it's still the most promising lead I've seen since I posted this question a year and a half ago. :)

Comment: I didn't quite get my image up and running in Qemu. There are a lot of imitations with Qemu and I've reverted to using a real RPi again.